# Multiple Linear Regression ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I've been trying to get my linear regression model to predict ticket prices to a certain destination, however, I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 3 is different from 1)
```

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df.dropna(inplace=True)
x = df[["Distances","Flight_time","Total_Staff_Pay"]]
y = df[["Price"]]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, train_size = 0.5, test_size = 0.5, random_state=1)
regression = LinearRegression()
regression.fit(x_train,y_train)


#predicting airport
a = [[3417.33],[7.30178432893716],[4804.57408844065]]
print(regression.predict(a))
```

I've seen the other questions/answers, they didn't really help.

Comment: try `a = [[3417.33,7.30178432893716,4804.57408844065]]`. Share data so the error can be reproduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

`a = [[3417.33,7.30178432893716,4804.57408844065]]`

A row represents an observation & therefore should be passed as `1x3`instead of`3x1`